# reduce в digital_root

Tags: javascript

Ребята, здравствуйте.
Делаю задания на codewars, не могу понять, почему последняя итерация `reduce` возвращает конкатенацию вместо сложения.

```js
function digital_root(n) {
  // ...
  n = n.toString().split('');
  console.log('n', n)
  n = n.reduce( function(total, current){
    console.log(parseFloat(total), parseFloat(current));
    console.log('parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(current)', Number(total) + Number(current))
    return Number(total) + Number(current);
  })
  
  if (n.toString().split('').length > 1) {
    digital_root(n)
  }
  
  return n
}

console.log(digital_root(132189));
```

Comment: Не увидел конкатенации, уточните что именно вам не понятно.

Comment: тебе не хватает одного return

Comment: @Grundy, можешь уточнить где именно?

Comment: `digital_root(n)`

Answer (score 3):

В приведенном коде результат рекурсии нигде не используется.

На самом деле 24 - это не склейка 2 и 4, а сумма цифр 132189, просто из-за кучи console.log возникла путаница что где выводится.

Для решения достаточно возвращать результат рекурсии, если на текущей итерации получилось число с несколькими цифрами

```js
function digital_root(n) {
  // ...
  n = n.toString().split('');
  console.log('n', n)
  n = n.reduce(function(total, current) {
    console.log(parseFloat(total), parseFloat(current));
    console.log('parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(current)', Number(total) + Number(current))
    return Number(total) + Number(current);
  })

  if (n.toString().split('').length > 1) {
    return digital_root(n)
  }

  return n
}

console.log(digital_root(132189));
```